# How can I solve Linux Installer not showing partitions correctly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have a 120 GB SSD and a 500 GB HDD on my computer. I wanted to install Linux [(Zorin OS)](https://zorinos.com/) on my machine. Windows 10 is installed on the SSD while the HDD has 3 partitions. I have one partition empty for Linux. But when I ran the installer, it shows the partitions incorrectly.

**Actual Partitions**

[image: partitions]

**Partitions shown by the installer**

[image: linux-installer]

It actually shows all the **3 partitions** as **1 partition**. Is there a way I can install Linux on my drive G now?

Edit: I can mount Drive G via Linux liveboot. Only the installer has the issue

Comment: Note it says the yellowish-green color is "simple volume". Simple volumes are the dynamic-disk equivalent of the primary partitions and logical drives found on basic disks. ([source](https://www.diskinternals.com/glossary/simple_volumes/)). Then [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381351/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I can still mount those partitions and they also show up in the **Disks** app. Then why not only the installer. There might be a way to convert it maybe.